# Add existing .pdf to report?

Tags: pdf, activereports

Is possible add existing `pdf` file to ActiveReports 6 report?
We have two application.
First application create report and save it as `pdf` in shared folder.
Second application create own report and if report from first application exists - user want that report of first application will be added to report of second application.

Applications have different database. So regenerating first report not a solution for this case.
`pdf` combining is one workaround - which can be used if no solutions will be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far answer for question is No, it is not possible.
From Internet found only that in DataDynamic(ActiveReports is/was a part of DataDynamics) reports is property

> "append existing .pdf to report"

But ActiveReports is another product, which haven't this possibilities.

In my case we decide to use @Issam workaround(save .rdf file to another folder and use it later with another report).
I accepted own answer, only because the reason, question was created, was to check if this kind of possibility exists for ActiveReports

Comment: I realize this is a little late to the party but what we ended up doing was using iTextSharp to handle the processing of pdf merger after the fact.  We create anywhere from 2-30 different individual reports and we found that iTextSharp has a PDFMerger method where you can pass it in a list of files and it will combine them into one.  Works like a charm, if you don't have a hangup with 3rd party tools.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherKlein, this workaround we trying too, but because of some problem with printing `pdf` files, we want to print straight from `ActiveReports` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're describing with the rdf file format 'activereports' built in format.  Not with pdf.  However, once the second report is generated and the two documents ar combined you can export them to pdf

Comment: Thanks, this can be another approach. But then we need to save `.rdf` file to same shared folders where all users have full access. Customers/users do not want application files(not `.pdf` reports) in their folder.